# Access array variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**this is my module**

```
function order_alert($email){

        $this->db->select("tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile");
        $this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
        $this->db->where('tbl_customer_registration.cus_email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($query->result()) ;

}
```

It return the following result for the above code

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cus_mobile] => 0716352642
        )

)
```

In the contoller I use foreach

```
foreach($result as $row) :
echo $row['cus_mobile'];
```

to get `[cus_mobile]` out of the above array but it gives me all `[cus_mobile]` rows in the `tbl_customer_registration`.

How do I get the only `[cus_mobile] => 0716352642` out of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$row->cus_mobile
```

since you have an array of objects.. not really sure if i got your question

**(UPDATED)**
Try this..

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
   echo $row->cus_mobile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got well your question, what your doing is retrieving data as array of objects and trying to access its data as pure array. To do so as you mean you might retrieve data result as an array there is method called `result_array()` you might use it instead `$query->result()`.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($query->result_array()) ;

foreach($result as $key => $row) :
echo $row['cus_mobile'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function order_alert($email){

    $this->db->select("tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile");
    $this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
    $this->db->where('tbl_customer_registration.cus_email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows()==1)
    $result_row = $query->row();
    return $result_row;
    else 
    return false;
```

}

```
    foreach($result_row as $row) {
    echo $row->cus_mobile;
    }
```

This will work for if result has one row... now to need to handle the case for greater than one row.Thanks